# Android app does not display parsed Jsoup information

Tags: java, android

I have the following code in an AsyncTask class (purpose to log in to my student gradebook, retrieve grades, and for now output to log):

```
private class infoGetter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        String studentID = studentID2.getText().toString();
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();

        String loginURL = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents/j_security_check";
        String userDataUrl = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?module=" + module + "&action=" + action + "&mpToView=" + mp + "&studentid=" + studentID;

        Connection.Response res = null;
        Document doc = null;

        try {

            res = Jsoup.connect(userDataUrl)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.4 Safari/537.36")
                    .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
                    .timeout(500)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            Log.e("connecting","first connection");

        } catch (IOException io) {

            io.printStackTrace();

        }

        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect(loginURL)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.4 Safari/537.36")
                    .referrer("https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?gohome=true")
                    .cookies(res.cookies())
                    .data("j_username", username)
                    .data("j_password", password)
                    .post();

            Log.e("connecting","second connection");


        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            ioe.printStackTrace();

        }

        Log.e("connecting","about to check if doc is null");

        if (doc != null){

            Log.e("MESSAGE","doc is not null");

            //everything works fine up to here!!

            Elements fGrade = doc.select("[width=70%]");

            for(Element e : fGrade) {

                Log.e("Grade: ",e.text());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

However, upon running my app and logging in (correct credentials), I do not get any log messages containing my grades at all. My Jsoup code should be correct, as I created a test project using java as a preface to my app, which worked flawlessly. However, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong!

All help is appreciated as always!

UPDATE: So using different logs, I have narrowed down the error to a point somewhere around/after where I am using the "doc.select()" invocation. However, I still don't see anything wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out my school decided to update their gradebook's UI so my query was actually incorrect. Everything working fine with updated query.